# What's the measure of the segment $PQ$ if the side of square $ABCD$ measures $a$?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For refernce: In the figure, $P$ and $Q$ are points of tangency.
Calculate $PQ$ if the side of square $ABCD$ measures $a$.

My progress:
[image]

$AQ = AD (tangents)\\\therefore AQ = AD = a\\similarly; AP = AQ = a\\
\therefore \triangle APD: \triangle AQG: \triangle APQ \rightarrow isosceles\\
EG =GH= \frac{a}{2}\\
\angle AGD = 45^o \therefore AG = \frac{a\sqrt2}{2}$

any hint where to use PQ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note $EQ \perp AQ, ED = EQ, AD = AQ$. So, $\triangle DAE \sim \triangle QAE $ and $\angle DAE = \angle QAE = \alpha$ (say).

Then, $\angle PAI = 2 \alpha - 45^\circ$

$PQ = 2 PI = 2 AP \sin (2 \alpha - 45^\circ)$

$PQ = \sqrt2 ~a (\sin 2\alpha - \cos 2\alpha) \tag1$

Now note in $\triangle ADE$ that $\cos \alpha = \frac{2}{\sqrt5}, \sin \alpha = \frac{1}{\sqrt5}$

$\implies \sin 2\alpha = \frac{4}{5}, \cos 2\alpha = \frac{3}{5}$

Plugging into $(1)$, $PQ = \frac{a \sqrt2}{5}$

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you consider the area of the kite $ADEQ$ you get
$$\overline{AD}\cdot \overline{DE} = \frac{\overline{AE}\cdot \overline{DQ}}2,$$
hence $\overline{DQ} = \frac2{\sqrt 5} a.$
Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle DCQ$ yields $\overline{CQ} = \frac1{\sqrt 5}a$. Now, calling $\overline{QI} = x$, and applying again Pythagorean Theorem on $\triangle CQI$ and $\triangle AQI$ gives the equation
$$\sqrt{\frac15a^2 - x^2} + \sqrt{a^2-x^2} = \sqrt 2 a.$$
Squaring both sides and reordering yields
$$2a^2 + 5x^2 = 5\sqrt{\frac15a^4-\frac65 a^2x^2 +x^4}.$$
Squaring again finally takes us to
$$50a^2x^2-1 = 0$$
that is $x = \frac1{5\sqrt 2} a$. Hence $\overline{PQ} = 2x = \frac{\sqrt 2}5a$.